Github actions output
I'm trying to get the output from a previous Github Actions step into the next step.
I have checked all the .env variables but unfortunately the output in the next step is still empty.
Does someone know what's going wrong here?
name: Stripe Service
on: [ push ]

env:
  AWS_REGION: eu-central-1
  AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME: StripeService
  DEPLOY_TYPE: development

jobs:
  build:
    name:  Build & Test Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      image: ${{ steps.build.outputs.image }}

    steps:
      - name:  Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      
      - name: ☁ Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
      
      - name: ☁ Login to AWS ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v2

      - name:  ☁ Build & Push Docker Image to AWS ECR
        env: 
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: stripe-service
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ env.DEPLOY_TYPE }}-${{ github.sha }}
        id: build
        run: |
          docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          echo "image=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
  
  deploy:
    name: ☁ Deploy Image to Production (AWS Lambda)
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build

    steps:
      - name: ☁ Deploy Docker Image as AWS Lambda function
        env:
          IMAGE: ${{ needs.build.outputs.image }}
        run: echo "$IMAGE"


Could you add a last step checking the image output value, in the build job? I don't know if this is related, but also try removing the " around $GITHUB_OUTPUT, they shouldn't be necessary: echo "image=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

Try to add echo statements to your steps to test values at each step. I hope this helps in identifying each step and tings are working as expected. It is difficult to debug things just by looking at it. Using echo statements helps a lot.

I found the solution, I forget to add the mask-aws-account-id: 'no' to the Configure AWS Credentials step. After that it's working now and outputting the correct value. Github actions said that it skipped outputting because it may contained a secret. The only secret it contains is my AWS account ID, which isn't a problem at all.
